# Why is a ‘Q’ added to the ticker symbol of a bankrupt company?

Tags: united-states, stocks, terminology, bankruptcy, ticker-symbols

I read on [investopedia.com](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/bankruptpublicfirm.asp#:%7E:text=What%20Bankruptcy%20Means%20to%20Shareholders,company%20has%20filed%20for%20bankruptcy.):

> If it's a [Chapter 11](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/chapter11.asp) bankruptcy, common stock shares will become practically worthless and will stop paying [dividends](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dividend.asp). The stock may be delisted on the major [stock exchanges](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/basics/04/092404.asp), and a Q may be added to the stock symbol to indicate that the company has filed for bankruptcy.

Why is a ‘Q’ added to the ticker symbol of a bankrupt company?

Comment: What the suffix letter represents (as in Q for bankruptcy) is relevant.  Why they chose that letter is useless information.

Comment: @BobBaerker some investors prefer to understand how the terms were chosen. Eg https://money.stackexchange.com/q/49323/5656 was well-received.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://redd.it/zrztsu), the `Q` doesn't stand for anything. Quotes below.

From [SirGlass](https://www.reddit.com/user/SirGlass):

> I don't think it means anything , Some of the symbols relate to the letter , A means class A shares, B means class b shares , W means warrant, R means rights issue , F foreign shares; but then lots just were assigned a random letter. So I do not think the Q means anything they just had to pick a random un-used letter because B was already taken. https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/nasdaqfifthletter.asp

From [royhenderson771](https://www.reddit.com/user/royhenderson771):

> It doesn't stand for anything. It simply acts as a way for investors to know the company filed for bankrupty. From the SEC: “Q” is for Caution

Answer (score 4):

[`Q` is for "Caution"](https://www.finra.org/investors/alerts/stock-information-buying-stock). The letter itself denotes that the ticker is for a company in bankruptcy proceedings. Which you knew already since you said so in the question.

There are many letters used for different situations, [Investopedia lists some of them](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/nasdaqfifthletter.asp). Trying to guess the meaning just by looking at the letter is pointless. They may differ between exchanges (e.g.: NASDAQ no longer uses the `Q`, but NYSE does). The historical context on how the letters were chosen is irrelevant for making financial decisions.